# what is the difference between "be required to" and "have to"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In this sentence,

> a candidate  for the post of a constable in London Metropolitan Force 
>   **is required to/ has to** be minimum six feet in height or an advocate  appearing  before the High Court  or Supreme Court  **is
>   required  to / has to** wear gowns and  wing collars.

Is there any meaning difference when I change each other?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, however "required to" is more formal and should be used in this context.

Comment: So, there's no difference in general?

Comment: @alryosha Other than a change in tone and formality, no. As Inazuma suggested, "is required to" in this case is more formal and preferable given the context.

Comment: @alryosha, In common speech, I would say 'have to' can be interpreted more broadly. So it can mean 'required to', 'must', 'should' (for my own good) etc. 'Required to' is often more explicit, like formal requirements for a job posting.

Comment: "Required to" suggests an external requirement.  "Have to" may be external but not necessarily--e.g., "I have to buy food today".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say that someone has to do something means that there is some reason why it is necessary for the person to do it, or be it, in a particular set of circumstances, it is quite generic as to what the reason might be.

> I have to go to Liverpool tomorrow.

I may have been ordered to go. I may have paid for a ticket. I may have promised to attend a friends wedding. I may have a medical appointment (which I choose not to miss). I may be sailing to Belfast early the following morning which necessitates going to Liverpool tomorrow if I am to catch my boat. I may just feel the need to get away from Manchester,  or be planning some shopping.

Being required can mean the same but more specifically a requirement, in this sense, is a demand or compulsory expectation placed upon a person by someone in authority.

One of the definitions of require in the  [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/require) is

> (of someone in authority) instruct or expect (someone) to do something.
>
> An advocate appearing before the High Court has to wear gowns and wing collars

and

> An advocate appearing before the High Court is required to wear gowns and wing collars

are both correct. There is a rule, which certain persons in a certain situation must obey. Therefore they are required to do it, and so we can say they have to do it.

However

> A candidate for police constable has to be six feet tall

is not a rule  which candidates for police constable are expected to obey. A person who is five feet and eleven inches tall is not ordered to grow another inch. You cannot say that a short person is required to be a tall person. In saying that a candidate has to be six feet, one is placing a restriction on who can be a candidate, not laying out a rule which candidates must follow.

> A candidate for police officer is required to be six feet tall

is not the best way of expressing that only persons who are already six feet tall may become candidates, because it could mean that short candidates are ordered to grow. We could say candidates  are required to report to Scotland Yard, or attend an induction course. Therefore in that case "have to " is better.